# PL\SQL Exceptions handling between functions

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

I have a first procedure like this

```
procedure p1(a in varchar2)
is 
begin 
  -- call second procedure
  p2(a);
  -- other things
end;
```

My second procedure may have an exception to raise:

```
procedure p2(a in varchar2)
is
  lv varchar2(20);
begin
   select '1' into lv from dual;

   if lv = '2' then
     raise general_exception;
   end if;
end;
```

My `general_exception` variable is a global exceptions type, inside the package where both of my procedures are in.

I want to catch the exception in the first procedure `p1` to avoid the execution of the other things.

I've tried this, but with no results:

```
procedure p1(a in varchar2)
is 
begin 
  -- call second procedure
  p2(a);
  -- other things
exception when general_exception then
  dbms_output.put_line('ERROR');
end;
```

Comment: so what happens?  What error is raised?  Show us where you declare general exception.. are P1 and P2 inside a package?

Comment: "My general_exception variable is a global exceptions type, inside the package where both of my procedures are in."

Comment: When I say "with no results" it means that I can to "other things" and the general_exception is not handled. So... no error raised.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is actually being raised? It never will be by the code you posted of course. Hopefully your real p2 doesn't handle the exception itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me (nb. I did change your p2 to reference the parameter being passed in, rather than the static value of '1'!):

```
create or replace package test_pkg
as
  general_exception exception;

  procedure p1 (p_a in varchar2);
end test_pkg;
/

create package body test_pkg
as
  procedure p2 (p_a in varchar2)
  is
  begin
    if p_a = '2' then
      raise general_exception;
    end if;
  end p2;

  procedure p1 (p_a in varchar2)
  is
  begin
    p2(p_a);
    dbms_output.put_line('p2 executed sucessfully. Do all of the things.');
  exception
    when general_exception then
      dbms_output.put_line('ERROR');
  end p1;
end test_pkg;
/

set serveroutput on;

begin
  test_pkg.p1('1');
  test_pkg.p1('2');
end;
/
```

And the output of running the p1 procedure with the two different values was:

```
p2 executed sucessfully. Do all of the things.
ERROR
```

which is as expected.

Comment: I found the problem. In my real procedures, I have some code who calls other procedures who have exception when others statement. That's why p2 never handle the error. Thank you very much to both for your answers. As I said, this was really a simple problem. I missed the focus! :)

Comment: No worries; it's easily done! We've all been there *{:-)